# How to include Select2.js in .net core app?

Tags: asp.net-core

I installed Select2.js as a Nuget package in my asp.net core app, but when I call the select2 function in my view I get `select2 is not a function` error. Do I need to do something elese except for installing the package?

Comment: Can you share your view with us, I want to see you implementation style...

Comment: Also please share your layout.cshtml

Comment: For ASP.NET Core, recommended approach is bower / npm. NuGet is recommended for server side packages. So you need to install via bower and add reference via script tag

Comment: @Anuraj Yeah, I installed  it via bower

Comment: After installing it via bower, do I need to include it in my view file?

Comment: @eli: Of course. Installing the package (via NuGet or bower/npm) merely puts the files in your project. It will never modify your views. The generated HTML must actually reference the script, or you cannot use it.